# How to disable render HTML code of certain ID of gravity form?

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

I need to disable render `HTML` of a certain id in my `Gravity Form.`

I already found something like this:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_content', function ( $field_content, $field, $value ) {
    if ( $field->id == 2 ) {
        if ( $field->is_entry_detail_edit() ) {
            $value = esc_attr( $value );
            $name  = 'input_' . esc_attr( $field->id );

            return "<input type='hidden' name='{$name}' value='{$value}'>";
        } elseif ( $field->is_entry_detail() ) {
            return '';
        }
    }

    return $field_content;
}, 10, 3 );
```

That one will hide my id, but `HTML` is stil rendered.

I suppose I need to use `filter => gform_pre_render`

Someone has some advice for me, please?

Comment: Can you be clearer in what you mean by 'disable render HTML'? If you don't want the form to output, can't you just remove it from the page?

Comment: For example, I defined the input text with id 13 in my form, but I want it not to be displayed and also to not render its HTML. That all I need. I used gform_field_content like I said, but it only hide element. HTML is still rendered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have given prevents the html being output on the entry detail section. Not the main form output.

Try something like this:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_content', function ( $field_content, $field, $value ) {
    if ( $field->id == 2 ) {
        // Show the field in entry_detail and form editor
        if ( GFCommon::is_entry_detail_view() || GFCommon::is_form_editor()) {
            return $field_content;
        }

        // Otherwise don't show the field
        return '';
    }

    // Show all other fields
    return $field_content;
}, 10, 3 );
```

If you want to remove the container list-item tag also try this:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_container', function ( $field_container, $field, $form, $css_class, $style, $field_content ) {
    if ( GFCommon::is_entry_detail_view() || GFCommon::is_form_editor()) {
        return $field_container;
    }
    if ( $field->id == 2 ) {
        return '';
    }
    return $field_container;
}, 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But some html is still rendered :

Comment: <li id="field_1_11" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible"></li> . I connect gravity form with Custom Post Type. and when I do not entered some input in my post I wanna completely skip this id to be rendered. Probably this is all I can do

Comment: I've tested this, and it does not render the HTML. Note that I edited this answer after I posted it. Are you sure you're using the correct code? Also don't forget to alter the id in my code if you're copying+pasting.

Comment: Yes I used this one: add_filter( 'gform_field_content', function ( $field_content, $field, $value ) {
    if ( $field->id == 1 ) {
        // Show the field in entry_detail and form editor
        if ( GFCommon::is_entry_detail_view() || GFCommon::is_form_editor()) {
            return $field_content;
        }

        // Otherwise don't show the field
        return '';
    }

    // Show all other fields
    return $field_content;
}, 10, 3 );

Comment: You cannot remove the <li> wrapper tag using this method... this method only removes the html of the actual field. See my edit in order to do this.

Comment: And when I want to remove li wrapper also? Is that even possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203113/discussion-between-leigh-bicknell-and-matus-vrsansky).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
function remove_field_by_id($objForm)
{        
    foreach ($objForm['fields'] as $iIndex => $objField) {
        // if its the one you want to remove ...
        if ($objField->id == 3) {
            // replace that field object with an empty array
            array_splice($objForm['fields'], $iIndex, 1, array());
        }
    }
    return $objForm;
}
add_filter('gform_pre_render', 'remove_field_by_id');
```